# How to implement ROT13 on a string using python code to demonstrate string encryption?

Tags: python-2.7, rot13

I am trying to use the ROT 13 caeser cipher for a college encryption assignement in Python but I have no proper idea as to how it can be used. This is what I tried:

```py
def rot13(s):
    Alphabets="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWEXYZ"
    type (Alphabets)
    Rotate=Alphabets[13:]+ Alphabets[:13]
    Reus= lambda a: Rotate[Alphabets.find(a)]
    if Alphabets.find(a)>-1:
    else: s
    return ''.join(Reus(a) for a in s)
    rot13('rageofbahamut')
```

Is there any procedural guideline that can explain how to use this cipher? Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt and show it to us, describing the problems you have with it.

Comment: I believe you would get better answers if you provide us with code what you already have, tell us why it does not behave the way you want it to, and then we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will encrypt using ROT13.  Or any other rotation value you wish to use.

```
alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

def encrypt(plain, rot):
    cipherText = ''

    for letter in plain:
        if letter in alphabet:
            cipherIndex = (alphabet.index(letter) + rot) % 26 # This handles the wrap around
            cipherText = cipherText + alphabet[cipherIndex]
        else:
            cipherText = cipherText + letter # Non alphabet characters are just appended.
    return cipherText

plain = 'HELLO WORLD'
rot = 13 # In case you want to change it
print encrypt(plain,rot)
```